# Calcular la diferencia entre un valor anterior y un valor siguiente en Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Buenas, necesito realizar un cálculo que me traiga la diferencia entre un valor actual y un valor anterior.....

El equema sería el siguiente:

```
Fecha | Costo | Diferencia
15/02 | 1500  |  0
17/02 | 1600  |  100
19/02 | 1500  |  100
20/03 | 1500  |  0
:
:
```

La columna diferencia es la que quiero obtener, que sería la diferencia entre los valores de la columna Costo.

Comment: según esa estructura ya tendrías el valor de diferencia almacenado no? si no es así podrías crear un trigger para que cada vez que tengas un insert en esa tabla recuperes el valor anterior, hagas la diferencia e insertes el valor con la diferencia ya calculada

Comment: @AnaLizR. Lo que quieres saber es ¿Cómo hacer un consulta `sql` para obtener la diferencia entre el valor actual y anterior de un registro en base a su fecha de una tabla de `Access`?

Comment: José-Ramón P. R. gracias por intentar responder, pero para ello la pregunta primero necesita reabrirse, ya he votado para la reapertura pero eso puede llevar un poco de tiempo y mas votos